# which pattern should be for this implements?

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns, implementation

I am overriding Spring's MessageSource to get Message Source from Database(Currenly SQLite).

As you see in CachedMessageSourceDao.java (Subject), whenever insertMessage invoked the CachedMessageSource.java(Observer) get notified. because it's observer pattern!!

All work fine except for initializing CachedMessageSourceDao.java (Subject).

DualKeyMap MESSAGES <--This should be filled up even if it's not notified at first.

But I have no idea how to implements. Could you tell me which design pattern should work for this?

---

**ApplicationContext.xml**

```
<bean id="cachedMessageSourceDao" class="org.springframework.context.support.CachedMessageSourceDao">
        <constructor-arg name ="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <constructor-arg name="DATABASE" value="BytoCms"/>
        <constructor-arg name="TABLE" value="MessageSource"/>
        <constructor-arg name="USE" value="1" type="int"/>
        <constructor-arg name="NOT_IN_USE" value="0" type="int"/>
        <constructor-arg name="ALL" value="99" type="int"/>
        <constructor-arg name="messageSource" ref="messageSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.CachedMessageSource" />
```

---

**CachedMessageSource.java (Observer)**

```
public class CachedMessageSource implements MessageSource, Observer {

    /** Message Storage */
    private static DualKeyMap<String, Locale, String> MESSAGES;

    ...more

@Override
public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
    try {
        MESSAGES = ((CachedMessageSourceDao) o).selectAllMessages();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Message Initializing Failed");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

---

**CachedMessageSourceDao.java (Subject)**

```
public class CachedMessageSourceDao extends Observable {
    private DataSource dataSource;
    private String DATABASE;
    private String TABLE;
    private int USE;
    private int NOT_IN_USE;
    private int ALL;

    public CachedMessageSourceDao(
            DataSource dataSource, 
            String DATABASE, 
            String TABLE,
            int USE,
            int NOT_IN_USE,
            int ALL,
            CachedMessageSource messageSource) {

        this.dataSource = dataSource;
        this.DATABASE = DATABASE;
        this.TABLE = TABLE;
        this.USE = USE;
        this.ALL = ALL;
        this.NOT_IN_USE = NOT_IN_USE;

        addObserver(messageSource); //★add Observer★
        notifyObservers(); //★This for initializing★
    }

    ...more

    public synchronized void insertMessage(String code, String value, String language) throws Exception {
        //Duplicate Message Check
        if(selectMessage(code, language) != null) throw new SQLException("Duplicate message exists for code: " + code + " and" + "language: " + language);

        String sql = "INSERT INTO " + TABLE + " (code, value, language, flag) values (?, ?, ?, " + USE + ")";

        Connection conn = null;
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;

        try {
            conn = dataSource.getConnection();
            conn.setAutoCommit(true);
            pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            pstmt.setString(1, code);
            pstmt.setString(2, value);
            pstmt.setString(3, language);
            pstmt.execute();

        } catch(SQLException ex) {

            ex.printStackTrace();

        } finally {

            try {

                if(pstmt != null) pstmt.close();
                if(conn != null) conn.close();

            } catch (SQLException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            }

        }
        notifyObservers(); //Realtime apply to MessageSource
    }
```